# AWS Lambda with API Gateway Integration returning 200 status_code even when calling SageMaker Endpoint doesn't return a response in lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway

I am calling deployed sagemaker Endpoint from lambda for load testing and lambda is getting called from api gateway integration when I am making call using gate POST rest api(with API Proxy Integration Enabled) from client side. But always rest api with lambda returning 200 even when invoke_endpoint doesn't return anything due to traffic load on SageMaker Endpoint.

```
@logger.inject_lambda_context(correlation_id_path=correlation_paths.API_GATEWAY_REST)
@tracer.capture_lambda_handler
def lambda_handler(event: dict, context: LambdaContext) -> dict:
# return app.resolve(event, context)

try:
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    print(type(event), '--> ', event)
    payload = event['data']
    print(payload)

    response  = runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME, 
                                              ContentType='application/json', 
                                              Body=json.dumps(payload),
                                              Accept='Accept')
    print(response)
    print(response.keys())
    # if "errorMessage" in str(respone.text):
    #     return
    if "errorMessage" in response.keys() and "502 Bad Gateway" in str(response):
        return {'statusCode': 502,'body': response}
    elif "errorMessage" in response.keys():
        return {'statusCode': 504,'body': response}
        
    result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
    return result
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    exception_handler(e)
```

I enabled API Integration proxy while creating api method in api gateway and using [`aws-lambda-powertools`](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/2.6.0/core/event_handler/api_gateway/#application-load-balancer)  to resolve the error but still client is getting 200 response always event my SageMaker Endpoint is not responding in the code due to load.

Error example with 200 code is below:

```
{"errorMessage":"2023-01-16T15:23:25.132Z c1bf04bf-12f7-46ab-b9a3-ffb1865eed26 Task timed out after 3.01 seconds"}
status_code: 200
```

Can anyone help me out here. Thanks in advance.

PS: I am very new to lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your lambda timeout limit.

[image]

Comment: even it timeout, I want to get 504 timeout code to client. it still responds timeout error message with 200 success code